# Plugin Manager is empty in Notepad++ under Wine on Linux

Tags: linux, notepad++, plugins, wine

I installed Notepad++ on Linux, using Wine. The editor itself works, but the Plugin Manager shows no plugins, saying `No new plugins available`:

[image]

I assume it's something related with Wine, it works in Windows on the same machine (I have dual-boot), so I doubt it's a network/proxy issue. There's [a question about it happening on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/379339/notepad-plugin-manager-shows-no-available-plugins), but none of the solutions there work for my case.

Comment: May be this will help: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14067/new-install-no-new-plugins-available/1

Comment: The link is about Windows, not Linux unfortunately.